# Hour Difference between 2 dates in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am using zend framework and i want to know the hour difference between 2 dates.
I know how to do it in core php using strtotime.

But i want it in Zend, if at all possible.

Ex: These are my dates in datetime format:

> 2011-04-13 23:00:00
>
> 2011-04-14 15:45:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a **`sub()`** method in [**`Zend_Date`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.overview.html) :

> `sub($date, $part = null, $locale =
>   null)` 
> Subtracts the `$part` of
>   `$date` having a locale `$locale` from
>   the current object's date.

Using `Zend_Date::HOUR` as $part should do the trick, I suppose :

```
$num_month = $firstDate->sub($secondDate, Zend_Date::HOUR);
```

As a sidenote : when working with `strtotime()`, dates are reprensented using [UNIX Timestamps](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Unix_time) -- which can only go from 1970 to 2038 *(on 32 bits systems, at least)*

It would probably wiser to work with the [**`DateTime`**](http://fr.php.net/datetime) class, which allows one to manipulate a *(virtually)* unlimited range of dates.

Comment: It is functional. THough we will have to create and object of Zend_Date. You always have answers MARTIn :-)

Comment: Well, if you are working with Zend_Date, you should use Zend_Date methods ; if not working with Zend_Date, of course... use something else ;-) *(not always ^^)*

Answer (score 4):

Why you want to have such function in Zend when you can do this thing with core PHP?

Just use core PHP.

Comment: I thought to use Zend for this purpose, and i hope there exists some function for achieving this.... but in core php, its always fine and simple though.

Comment: so why people out there invented frameworks  ??? to make our life easier , am i right ??

Comment: But then you will not expect an equivalent of echo in frameworks. Simple calculations can always be performed in core

Comment: Zend_Date is really usefull for date display and calculating dates before 1970 (0 time in unix), but if you have a lot of date manipulations to do, stick to PHP date(), strtotime() or the class DateTime. Otherwise you will get huge performance issues since Zend_Date rely heavily on i18n and locale

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i could achieve a solution this way:

```
$firstDay = new Zend_Date('2011-04-13 23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s');

$lastDay = new Zend_Date('2011-04-14 15:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s');

$diff = $lastDay->sub($firstDay)->toValue();

$days = ceil($diff/60/60);
```

Finally i could get the ceil value of 17, but could not get the exact difference (16h, 45min)